# Set localhost sessions folder to 0070 using OS X & MAMP

Tags: php, session, localhost

newb here, new to working with `localhost` in OS X.

I am running a MAMP stack on OS X. My session test file returns a series of warnings which I believe is due to the inability to write to the sessions folder which I have not been able to set to 0700.

I've checked for:

> white space
>   file path `http://localhost/sessions/`
>   folder name (sessions)
>   I believe the problem is a permission issue. I am looking to be able to write to my `localhost` directory session folder. To do this I need to set the permission of the folder to 0700. I am hoping to find an solution that I can replicate with my limited level of expertise at this time.

This is the code:

```
<?php
 ini_set('session.save_path','/htdocs/sessions');
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['test'] = "If you can read this, sessions are working!";
 print $_SESSION['test'] . "<br>";
 print "Session ID is: ". session_id()."<br>";
?>
```

These are the errors which only appear when i run local:

Warning: session_start(): open(/htdocs/sessions/sess_d1c5ef5a18bb844bfc667a0fc911191f, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 3

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php:3) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 3

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php:3) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 3
If you can read this, sessions are working!
Session ID is: d1c5ef5a18bb844bfc667a0fc911191f

Warning: Unknown: open(/htdocs/sessions/sess_d1c5ef5a18bb844bfc667a0fc911191f, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/htdocs/sessions) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

```
/htdocs/sessions
```

does it exist? And, why would you choose to use a root directory in MacOSX? Perhaps you should map it to your user folder.

```
/Users/username/htdocs/session
```

Comment: I might not have explained it correctly, i'm new to this. The path to my session fold is 'User/Machintosh HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sessions/'. I am trying to set/revise the permissions to the sessions folder. If i've done something silly, it's because i'm new and don't know better (the answer to 'why', with me, is likely always 'I didn't know better'). And yes it exists. That was the first thing I looked for.

Comment: Using terminal, I attempted the following terminal command, but it doesn't appear to have worked: chmod -R 700 sessions. I did confimr using the ls command that i was in the correct directory.